# Semi-supervised sentiment analysis in Python?

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I have been following this tutorial 
https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-sentiment-analysis-with-scikit-learn/
to create a sentiment analysis in python. However, here's what I don't understand: It seems to me that the data they use is already labeled? So, how do I use the training I did on the labeled data to then apply to unlabeled data?

I wanna do sth like this:

Assuming I have 2 dataframes:
df1 is a small one with labeled data, df2 is a big one with unlabeled data. I just finished training with df1. How do I then go about predicting the values for df2?

I thought it would be as straight forward as text_classifier.predict(df2.iloc[:,1].values), but that doesn't work for me.

Also, forgive me if this question may seem stupid, but I don't have a lot of experience with machine learning and nltk ...

EDIT:
Here is the code I'm working on:

```
enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
//chat_data = chat_data[:180]
//chat_labels = chat_labels[:180]

chat_labels = enc.fit_transform(chat_labels)
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer (max_features=2500, min_df=1, max_df=1, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
features = vectorizer.fit_transform(chat_data).toarray()
print(chat_data)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, chat_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

text_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200, random_state=0)
text_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = text_classifier.predict(X_test)



print(confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions))
print(classification_report(y_test,predictions))
print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))

chatData = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\jgott\OneDrive\Dokumente\Thesis\chat.csv")
unlabeled = chatData.iloc[:,1].values
unlabeled = vectorizer.fit_transform(unlabeled.astype('U'))
print(unlabeled)
//features = vectorizer.fit_transform(unlabeled).toarray()
predictions = text_classifier.predict(unlabeled)
```

Most of it is taken exactly from the tutorial, except for the line with astype in it, which I used to convert the unlabeled data, because I got a valueError that told me it can't convert from String to float if I don't do that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I use the training I did on the labeled data to then apply to
>   unlabeled data?

This is really the problem that supervised ML tries to solve: having **known** **labeled** data as inputs of the form `(sample, label)`, a model tries to discover the **generic patterns** that exist in these data. These patterns hopefully will be useful to predict the labels of **unseen** **unlabeled** data.

For example in sentiment-analysis (sad, happy) problem, the pattern that may be discovered by a model after training process:

Existence of one or more of this words means sad:

```
("misery" , 'sad', 'displaced people', 'homeless'...)
```

Existence of one or more of this words means happy:

```
("win" , "delightful", "wedding", ...)
```

If new textual document is given we will search for these patterns inside this document and we will label it accordingly.

As side note: we usually do not use the whole labeled dataset in the training process, instead we take a small portion from the dataset(other than the training set) to validate our model, and verify that it discovered a really generic patterns, not ones tailored specifically for the training data.

Comment: I see. In my case, I have personally labeled about 250 chatlines of a game, plus about 140k of unlabeled lines. I used the random forest classifier to train on 80% of the labeled data and used the rest as test and got a 65% accuracy. But now when I want to use it on the unlabeled data, I get ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 107 and input n_features is 2500 .... I will add some code in the op to make it easier to talk about